# What is this key for? Where is it used?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I recently bought the BioShock Infinite Strategy guide to help me in finding all the Voxelphones and other collectibles. It came with this key key ring which is used in-game, but I can't remember where from. Is it the key given to Elizabeth by Booker to escape from the tower, or used by Elizabeth near the end of the game?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the key they use to escape the tower.

[image: Booker giving the key to Elizabeth]

It was one of the items in the box Booker received from the lady in the boat at the very beginning of the game.

Comment: Note that the design of the key is such that if it is spun very quickly, the images of the bird and the cage merge so that it looks like the bird is in the cage. Which has no effect on anything but is a neat touch as well as a connection to the choice of pendants that occurs later in the game.

Comment: @technophile: It's called a [Thaumatrope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaumatrope). And of course, the first thing Elizabeth does is spin it for a moment.